# Does hadoop create InputSplits parallely

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, emr, amazon-emr

I have a large text file of size around 13gb. I want to process the file using Hadoop. I know that hadoop uses FileInputFormat to create InputSplits which are assigned to mapper tasks. I want to know if hadoop creates these InputSplits sequentially or in parallel. I mean does it read the large text file sequentially on a single host and create split files which are then distributed to datanodes, or does it read chunks of say 50mb in parallel?
Does hadoop replicate the big file on multiple hosts before splitting it up?

Is it recommended that I split up the file into 50mb chunks to speed up the processing? There are many questions on appropriate split size for mapper tasks but not the exact split process itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InputSplits are created in the client side and it just a logical representation of the file in the sense it would only contain the file path,start and end offset values(calculated from linerecordreader initialize function). So calculating this logical rep. will not take much time so need to split your chunks the real execution happens at the mapper end where the execution is done in a parallel way. Then the client places the inputsplits into hdfs and jobtracker takes it from there and depending on the splits it allocates a tasktracker. Now here one mapper execution is not dependent on the other. The second mapper knows very well that where it has to start processing that split, so the mapper executions are done in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to process the file using `MapReduce` not Hadoop. Hadoop is a platform which provide tools to process and store large size data.

1. When you store the file in HDFS (Hadoop filesystem) it splits the file into multiple blocks. The size of the block is defined in `hdfs-site.xml` file as `dfs.block.size`. For example, if `dfs.block.size=128` then your input file will be split into 128MB blocks. This is how HDFS store the data internally. For user it is always as a single file.
2. When you provide the input file (stored in HDFS) to MapReduce, it launches mapper task for each block/split of the file. This is default behavior.
3. you need not to split the file in chunks, just store the file in HDFS and it will the desired for you.

Answer (score 0):

First let us understand what is meant by input split.

When your text file is divided into blocks of 128 MB size (default) by hdfs, assume that 10th line of the file is divided and first half of the is in first block and the other half is in second block. But when you submit a Map Program, hadoop understands that the last line of 1st block (which becomes input split here) is not complete. So it carries the second half of the 10th line to first input split. Which implies,

1) 1st input split = 1st Block + 2nd part of 10th line from 2nd block

2) 2nd input split = 2nd Block - 2nd part of 10th line from 2nd block.

This is an inbuilt process of hadoop and you cannot change or set the size of input split. The block size of hadoop v2 is by default 128 MB. You can increase during installation but you cannot decrease it.